# Nested IF statements, can't return "0" because 2nd IF statement is in the way

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If it's the weekend, I want to calculate overtime hours only with .5hr break calculated in, and regular hours when its not the weekend. It works perfectly fine until i leave my "time in" and "time out" slots blank, then it automatically calculates the .5 in the first IF statement as a -.5 under overtime hours instead of leaving it at 0.00. Is there anyway around this?

```
=IF(WEEKDAY($A19,2)>5,(d19-c19)*24-**.5**,IF((D19-c19)*24>8,(d19-c19)*24-8.5,0
```

p.s. first time posting here, sorry if all this is messed up. Thanks for any help.

Comment: It would be helpful to see an example of your table to see what cells you are referencing. Welcome!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You will find that you will have a better
experience if you take moment to take the [Stack Overflow
tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You can also read about asking a [good
question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

If you follow the norms of the Stack Overflow community and approach it with an attitude of helping others too, it will serve you well.

Comment: I don't think that your second if statement will ever execute because anything greater than 8 will also be greater than 5. Also note I believe you are missing a `)`.

Comment: @JackMoody Ended up leaving work right after posting this, however, StoneGiant nailed it on the head and answered for me. Appreciate you're interested. If you'd like, I can still post what I've been working on so others might receive some help by it as well.

Comment: Glad you got it @DavidBenford!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to follow what you're asking, but here's my attempt to solve it based on some guesses about what you're saying:

**Assumptions:**

- Column A is the Day.
- Column C is Time In.
- Column D is Time Out.
- Weekend hours are always overtime.
- A 30 minute break is deducted from overtime hours on any given day.
- You are attempting to calculate the total of overtime hours per day.

**Step 1:** Make sure you have hours to even consider.

```
= IF((D19-C19) > 0,<do something here>,0)
```

**Step 2:** Do something different on weekdays v. weekends.

```
= IF((D19-C19) > 0, IF(WEEKDAY($A19,2)>5, <calculate weekend>, <calculate weekday>),  0)
```

**Step 3:** Calculate weekends, but never allow a negative number. (Assumption: If a person works 15 minutes overtime, that is no overtime at all.)

```
= IF( (D19-C19) > 0, 
      IF(WEEKDAY($A19,2)>5,
         MAX((D19-C19)*24-0.5, 0), <calculate weekday>),  0)
```

**Step 4:** Calculate weekdays, but never allow a negative number. (Assumption: If a person works 15 minutes overtime, that is no overtime at all.)

```
= IF( (D19-C19) > 0, 
      IF(WEEKDAY($A19,2)>5,
         MAX((D19-C19)*24-0.5, 0),
         MAX((D19-C19)*24-8.5, 0)
        ),
      0)
```

**Step 5:** Optimize - Since it looks like the MAX function handles the case when D19-C19 is 0, we don't need the outer IF statement

```
= IF(WEEKDAY($A19,2)>5,
     MAX((D19-C19)*24-0.5, 0),
     MAX((D19-C19)*24-8.5, 0)
    )
```

...and I think that gives you what you want.

Comment: My apologies for writing such a confusing question, but I think you answered exactly what I needed and I want to thank you! I've been beating my head over this for hours upon hours, thank you!

Comment: Glad to have been of help! Feel free to [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it was useful to you. :-) Here's a tip from the SO site: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Another question for you, is there a way to have the final IF statement not calculate the .5 break if the person worked less than 6 hours? I've tried using <6, >6, and so forth. Thanks ahead time!

Comment: Change the weekend part of the calculation to this: `MAX((D19-C19)*24-((D19-C19)*24>6)*0.5, 0)`.  If the value difference is greater than 6, the result of `((D19-C19)*24>6)` is 1, otherwise it is 0. Multiplying 0.5 by that will turn the deduction on and off. I feel bad for the PDBs that work 6.5 hours. ;-)

Comment: Haha I'm just trying to get it so that when we work on the weekends for less than 6hrs (company says we have to take a 30min lunch at that point), we don't get a break calculated in. Thanks again, wish there was a way to message you directly.